# How to phrase MySQL query to get daily totals for a column in groups?

Tags: mysql, row

I have the following table structure:

```
vote_id     date                    user       source
--------   ------                  ------     --------
1          2013-07-23 01:37:25     user1      x
2          2013-07-23 13:15:10     user2      y
3          2013-07-23 22:30:53     user3      x
4          2013-07-24 17:38:46     user1      y
```

What I want to get in a query is the number of votes per day for each source. The issue is that I record the date to the second, but I want it sorted by day in the query.

e.g. The result would be something like this:

```
2013-07-23    source: x     votes: 10
2013-07-23    source: y     votes: 2

2013-07-24    source: x     votes: 0
2013-07-24    source: y     votes: 6
2013-07-24    source: z     votes: 3
```

So for every day there will be the total number of votes per source (the number of sources isn't specified, it can be anything).

Any ideas? This query is a bit above me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`date`) as day,
  COUNT(user) as votes,
  source
FROM  Tablename
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE()` function to extract date out of complete `datetime` field.

```
Select DATE(date) Day, Source, Count(*) Votes
From Table
Group By DATE(date) Day, Source
```